# How to use Exif library to roate an image?

Tags: javascript

I have an image tag :

```
<img id="productPhoto0" src="...."></img>
```

Later I load some url from db and want to load it AND **rotate** it.

```
        var element=document.getElementById("productPhoto0" );
        if(element) element.src=data.media.photos[k];
       //call rotation function here on load finish
```

I have this library https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js , which works but i can't find out how to integrate it.

I would like to call this function AFTER the image was loaded into `element`

```
function rotateimg(src)
{

      //pass here my own image from above
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = src;
         image.onload = function() {
           EXIF.getData(image, function() {
              var orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
              console.log(orientation);
              switch(orientation) {
                case 3:
                  node.css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
                  break;
                case 6:
                  node.css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
                  break;
                case 8:
                  node.css('transform', 'rotate(-90deg)');
                  break;
              }
          });
       };
}
```

Here they used a *new image*, but i would like to somehow pass it the div element and wait for load, then perform the rotation.

This will not work :

```
//pass the element
function rotateimg(element)
{

 element.onload = function() {
        EXIF.getData(element, function() {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just have to get rid of the extra rotateImage function and wrap the code inside the `if(element)` block, using **element** as the identifier.

```
var element=document.getElementById("productPhoto0" );    
if (element) {
      element.onload = function() {
        EXIF.getData(this, function() {
          var orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
          console.log(orientation);
          switch (orientation) {
            case 3:
              node.css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
              break;
            case 6:
              node.css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
              break;
            case 8:
              node.css('transform', 'rotate(-90deg)');
              break;
          }
        });
      };
      element.src = data.media.photos[k];
    }
```

Comment: Yes finally that's what i did, and i know it is a different issue but turns out this library will access some url, and i will get this error when i use it : Access to XMLHttpRequest  has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Not sure what to do with it.

Comment: That happens if the domain from which you're executing the javascript and the source of the image are different or if both sources are the same but the server does not return the appropriate header. You can try serving the image via a proxy. Append `https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=` to the url.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So it has nothing to do with the library ? because if i remove it and simply load the images it works (the domain and the photos have different urls)